# Associated random variables

Tags: probability, reference-request, random-variables

Can some one point some good references on associated sequences of random variables?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical reference is the paper [Association of Random Variables, with Applications](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/720/week02/esary-proschan-walkup-1967.pdf) by
J. D. Esary, F. Proschan, and D. W. Walkup, Ann. Math. Statist. Volume 38, Number 5 (1967), 1466-1474.

Answer (score 0):

A good treatise by BLSP Rao
Title:ASSOCIATED SEQUENCES, DEMIMARTINGALES AND NONPARAMETRIC INFERENCE
Pub: Springer 2011